# The radiobuttons cannot be unselected by default

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
def booking(self):
        self.book_win = tk.Tk()
        self.book_win.geometry('1000x600')

        self.fm7 = tk.Frame(self.book_win,width=300,height=500)
        self.fm7.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=3,columnspan=2)

        self.fm8 = tk.Frame(self.book_win,width=300,height=500)
        self.fm8.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=3,columnspan=2)

        
        self.book_title = tk.Label(self.fm7,text='Room Prices per night',font=('Helvetica',24))
        self.book_title.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)


        self.lb_deluxe = tk.Label(self.fm7,text='Deluxe Room',font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.lb_deluxe.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.pr1 = tk.Label(self.fm7,text=2050,font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.pr1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.lb_twin = tk.Label(self.fm7,text='Twin Bedroom',font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.lb_twin.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.pr2 = tk.Label(self.fm7,text=2500,font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.pr2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.lb_king = tk.Label(self.fm7,text='King Bedroom',font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.lb_king.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.pr3 = tk.Label(self.fm7,text=2890,font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.pr3.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.lb_harbour = tk.Label(self.fm7,text='Harbour View Room',font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.lb_harbour.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.pr4 = tk.Label(self.fm7,text=3120,font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.pr4.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)


        self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.ck_breakfast = tk.Checkbutton(self.fm8,text='Breakfast',variable=self.var1,font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.ck_breakfast.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.lb_room = tk.Label(self.fm7,text='Type of Room',font=('Helvetica',20))
        self.lb_room.grid(row=6,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.var2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var2.set(' ')
        self.rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='Deluxe Room',variable=self.var2,value='Deluxe Room')
        self.rb1.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='Twin Bedroom',variable=self.var2,value='Twin Bedroom')
        self.rb2.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.rb3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='King Bedroom',variable=self.var2,value='King Bedroom')
        self.rb3.grid(row=8,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.rb4 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='Harbour View Room',variable=self.var2,value='Harbour View Room')
        self.rb4.grid(row=8,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
```

In this program, I would like to set all the radiobuttons at the beginning to be unselected. Although I tried `self.var2.set(' ')` it still does not work. I have already tried to find the solution and change thoroughly but there may have some problems occur. If possible can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Comment: Your code works fine to me when I add all of the missing pieces. None of the values are selected when it starts up. Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. My guess is that you have more than one instance of `Tk`, but without a complete example that's only a guess.

Comment: Try saying `self.var2 = tk.StringVar(master=self.book_win)` just to confirm the theory that you have more than one `Tk()` in someother function of your code.

Comment: It works now after changing that thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be creating more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need to create popup windows, use `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was that it has more than one instance of `Tk()` hence the `StringVar()` doesnt know which instance to belong to(by default the first created `Tk()`). So make all additional child windows to `Toplevel()` and just keep one `Tk()` for the entire code, unless you exactly know what your doing.

**Or** if you still wish to keep multiple `Tk()` then give a master to almost all the extra widgets or variables created(`StringVar`,`IntVar`,`PhotoImage`,etc) like:

```
self.var2 = tk.StringVar(master=self.book_win)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is might not work

```py
        self.var2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var2.set(None) #set this to none
        self.rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='Deluxe Room',variable=self.var2,value='Deluxe Room')
        self.rb1.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='Twin Bedroom',variable=self.var2,value='Twin Bedroom')
        self.rb2.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.rb3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='King Bedroom',variable=self.var2,value='King Bedroom')
        self.rb3.grid(row=8,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        self.rb4 = tk.Radiobutton(self.fm7,text='Harbour View Room',variable=self.var2,value='Harbour View Room')
        self.rb4.grid(row=8,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: Why would you post an answer that might not work? It's not at all clear what you did, please describe what you changed. Also, it definitely worn't work because it has broken indentation.